# What causes an iframe to open new links inside parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe src="http://astore.amazon.com/itbumobile-20?wmode=transparent" width="100%" height="6000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

In this iframe new links *are* opening inside parent window.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" height="6000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
```

In this iframe new links *are not* opening inside parent window.

But two iframe coding appears to be the same way. What is the actual trick of different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" target="_top">Top</a>

<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" target="_self">Self</a>
```

The magic of `target`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wxcufehg/

Comment: But there is no target inside these two iframe. Also target is not appearing inside the link of the iframe. But two iframe are acting differently.

Comment: @AsifIqbal - If you take a look at w3school's source, you can see that they do use `target="_top"`, for example: `<a href="html/default.asp" target="_top">Learn HTML</a>`

Comment: Yes, it is for linking a tag . But I am looking for iframe tag

Comment: @AsifIqbal - Looks like you don't understand what `target` is. There is a detailed explanation on what the `target` attribute does here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes).

Comment: May be I am not understanding. But Please see my initial 2 iframe code. There is no target attribute. Even after loading iframe in HTML file I do not see any target attribute inside iframe links.  But two iframes are acting differently.

Comment: @AsifIqbal - I don't know what you are talking about. There *is* `target` attributes in every link in w3school's website: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T75OA.png

Comment: Yes, It is for <a> tag. Not for <iframe> tag

Comment: If you were referring `iframe`s as "links", then, no, `iframe`s are not links. And the different behaviors are also not caused by the frame itself. It's the link itself that causes it to open in different places.

Comment: Please copy my iframe code in a html file. Then load the file. You will get navigation. But one iframe's navigation is working without changing your html file location and another navigation will change your url. I want to know this trick. Specially for my two iframes.

Comment: @AsifIqbal - It was not the `iframe`'s code that causes this difference in behavior. It was the `target` attribute of the links inside the `iframe` that caused it.  Take a look at my demo. The page is inside a frame and there are two links. One with `_top` and one with `_self`. When you click them, one opens in a new window and one opens in the same frame (changes location). Why? Because the `target` attribute caused it. The exact same thing is happening in your example.

Comment: No, there is no target attribute inside iframe page. I checked it using firefox ( Inspect element )

Comment: @AsifIqbal - I included a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T75OA.png) 6 comments before showing you the `target` attributes and you said there is no such attribute.

Comment: Page is loading in same window without attribute. Please see this screenshot http://postimg.org/image/oygwyksd5/

Comment: @AsifIqbal - That is the Amazon Store page. Since there is no `target` attribute, by default new pages will be opened in the same frame (`_self`). As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) says, "[_self] is the default if the attribute is not specified."

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AsifIqbal - Glad you finally get it.